Are the Odoo /web/sessions/authenticate and the /web/datasets enpoints disabled in Odoo 16?
I am trying to build an odoo client in Android. The /web/sessions/authenticate endpoint always returns Access Denied. Dont know if this endpoint has been removed in Odoo ver 16. As well as the /web/datasets. Anyone know?
